# Moving to next iteration of external loop from inside the nested loop Directly

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, c++17, nested-loops, break

I have a nested loop and in the internal loop I am doing a condition check and if that condition check Is satisfied i want to jump to the next iteration of the external loop.

It goes something like this

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ){
    for( int j = 0 ; j < n ; j++ ){
            if( condition ){
                // Move to next iteration of first or external loop 
                // skip the work and work2 both
            }
            // some work being done
            work(); 
        }
        work2(); 
}
```

What I mean here is If the condition is satisfied at **`i = 2`** and **`j = 5`**
I want to move to **`i = 3`**

Is there any way to do without using Booleans something similar to the break statement ?

Comment: You mean you don't want to check the `if( condition )` ?

Comment: You can set a boolean flag if the condition is met, break from the internal loop, and continue in the external loop if the flag is set. Or you can encapsulate your inner loop in a function that returns a boolean.

Comment: @cse i want to check the condition but if it true I want to end the internal loop and move to the next iteration of the external loop i.e if the condition is met at the 2 nd iteration of the external and 1st iteration of the internal loop I want to move directly at the 3rd iteration of the external loop

Comment: What about using `for( int j = 0 ; (j < n) && (condition) ; j++ )`?

Comment: You can set j greater than n

Comment: @LukeErickson Just attention, But in that case OP should use `if-else` not only `if` part.

Comment: You can put it in a lambda and call it inline. Then you can return from within the scope of the condition. It's a bit ugly, but works.

Comment: @LukeErickson but even in that the work() function will be called and its a very heavy function isnt there anything like a break ... I know I can set a conditional before work() to overcome that but i just wanted to know if there is a way to do it in one line which I dont think there is

Comment: @ASHUTOSHSINGH As I commented above, in that case you should use `if-else` not only `if` part.

Comment: @cse as i said above i know i can do it with conditionals but you see in the source which I, unfortunately, cannot share that will make the code very very unreadable as there are many of these conditions another way i know is to wrap all the conditions in a separate function to make the code a lot cleaner i think i will go with that.

Comment: @ASHUTOSHSINGH see my answer - it's essentially what you are saying (wrap in a separate function) but since we have lambdas now, no need to create yet another function just so that you can return from the condition

Comment: Please don't edit the question to list the provided answers.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from what was pointed out in the comments, which is to force the value of `j`, you can use a lambda and call it inline. It's a bit ugly but does the job:

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ){
    [&]() // OR [=]() OR [i, n]() depending on your usage
    {
        for( int j = 0 ; j < n ; j++ ){
            if( condition ){
                return;
            }
            // some work being done
            work(); 
        }
    }();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, dude this looks like something that will work for me. I will try this or wrapping all the condition in a single function and set it as a condition in the loop statement itself

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `condition` part in inner for-loop iteration check part.

As following:

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
{
    for( int j = 0 ; (j < n) && conditionCheckFunction() ; j++ )
    {
        work(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I am leaning to this answer and this is one the things I have half-implemented already

Answer (score 0):

If your condition is satisfied, just `break` out of the inner loop. The control flow will then go to the next iteration of the outer loop:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
    for(int j = 0 ; j < n ; j++) {
        if( condition ) {
            break;  // out of inner loop
        }
        work(); 
    }
}
```